# Limitations of the wss_logging database?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, logging

I select some data for statistic from the wss_logging database. 
(How often will each site called in the month)

No i realized that the stored data in the table (view) dbo.RequestUsage are only from the actual month.

Is it possible to extend the store, that it holds the data over 2 months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Usage Logging database can only store and display information via defined views to only a maximum of 31 days.
The following PowerShell command error validates my statement:

> Set-SPUsageDefinition : Cannot validate argument on parameter
>   'DaysRetained'. The 32 argument is greater than the maximum allowed
>   range of 31. Supply an argum ent that is less than 31 and then try the
>   command again.

```
Set-SPUsageDefinition -Identity <SPUsageDefinitionPipeBind> [-Enable] [-DaysRetained <0-31>] [-Verbose]
```

`Get-SPUsageDefinition` will list the definition Names with their current retention periods.

Comment: That's sad ... but thx a lot!